# How should I integrate Devise two factor authentication with custom sessions controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I integrated the Houdini two factor authentication with existing rails application.
First I doesn't have any custom sessions_controller then the ***two_factor_authentication*** is working fine.
But whereas I written custom create action in Sessions Controller then it doesn't authenticated by ***two_factor_authentication***.

Here is the custom code for create action of Sessions Controller.

```
  if status_response.nil?
    render :file => 'public/api_not_found.html', :status => :not_found, :layout => false
  else
    if status_response['code'].to_i == 1
      signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
      flash[:alert] = 'Invalid Email ID or password.'
      yield if block_given?
      respond_to_on_destroy
    else
      self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
      set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      yield resource if block_given?
      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    end
  end
```

Model code of user.rb:

```
  devise :two_factor_authenticatable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :confirmable, password_length: 8..30
  has_one_time_password


  def send_two_factor_authentication_code
    puts ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> otp_secret_key: #{otp_secret_key}, otp_code: #{otp_code}"
  end
```

I know if we are customizing the create action of Sessions Controller then we should call the ***two_factor_authentication***. I tried to invoke this in controller but it throws an error.

So my question how should i integrate the ***two_factor_authentication*** with custom create action of Session Controller?

Comment: "I tried to invoke this in controller" - what did you do exactly? "but it throws an error" - what error?

Comment: undefined method `scan' for nil:NilClass.      
puts ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> otp_secret_key: #{otp_secret_key}, otp_code: #{otp_code}"  
otp_secret_key and otp_code are nil here.
So, we need to perform same behavior which performs on devise create action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just wanted to use super.

```
    if status_response.nil?
      render :file => 'public/api_not_found.html', :status => :not_found, :layout => false
    else
      if status_response['code'].to_i == 1
        #If this is true then I didn't got auth_tok from API therefore i forcefully signed out the user.
      else
        super
      end
    end
```

So here I am checking the response of user and based on it I wanted to allow user to sign in.
And the another thing is the otp_code in the database should not be nil.   If it is nil then the 2FA will not work. It simply redirects it to root without asking otp_code.